# TINA in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, tina

I need ADS8321 for LTspice. I  used TINA-TI and when I download it, this is what I get.

[image]

What should I do? I can't use this as a library.

Comment: look at the name of the file you opened

Comment: @jsotola that's the only file I found, can you please send me the lib?

Comment: you are not understanding what I'm saying  ... look at the name of the file ... what does the name of the file tell you?

Comment: @jsotola it's another app, but how can I creat an ADC in TINA ?

Comment: it's not an app ... it's an archive